# how to store and set value of mat-input in object instead of string

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm getting  `formGroup.get('Style').` value in string, but I needed as object.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <mat-form-field class="full-width">
    <input matInput formControlName="Style" placeholder="{{'Style'}}" type="any">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

I want to get value of matInput in object, instead of string. for ex. if I put type= "number" and enter value 2 in matInput, form control will store the value 2 as a number. Similarly, if i write { 'background-color': '#4a90e2', 'margin-left': 10 } in matInput, formControl should store this value as Object instead of string

Comment: please explain bit more about what you want to achieve

Comment: Do you want to get `formControl` object? `formGroup.get('Style')` would give you that, where as `formGroup.get('Style').value` will give the string.

Comment: I want to get value of matInput in object, instead of string. for ex. if i put type= number, form control will store the value of matInput as a number. Similarly, if i write { 'background-color': '#4a90e2', 'margin-left': 10 } in matInput, formControl should store this value as Object

Comment: I would store as a string and then parse from JSON on change or when the value is needed. I would need more context to give more precise help.